# How to create a copy of all/most columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to leave the original set of columns in place but use a mapping to create copies with an updated column name.
For example, if the original existing dataframe has columns:

```
'first_name_2020','other_name_2020', 'last_name_2020'
```

I would want to input parameters:

```
forename = 'first_name_2020'
middlename = 'other_name_2020'
surname = 'last_name_2020'
previous_surname = None
```

Then output a dataframe that has the original set of columns but also has these additional ones with standardized naming added (including an empty column added for the missing name field). The set of columns is larger than three/four so I need to iterate through a list or dictionary/mapping rather than type multiple fixed-width column statements

have dataframe like:

```
df_in = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('JOHN','ANDREW','SMITH'),('JANE','MAY','JONES')]).toDF(['first_name_2020','other_name_2020','last_name_2020'])
```

want output df to look like:

```
df_out = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('JOHN','ANDREW','SMITH','JOHN','ANDREW','SMITH',''),('JANE','MAY','JONES','JANE','MAY','JONES','')]).toDF(['first_name_2020','other_name_2020','last_name_2020','forename','middlename','surname','previous_surname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, you just have to iterate thru the columns and copy it into a new_column

```
columns = df.columns
for col_name in columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name+”_new”, df[col_name])
```

And for the final empty column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = df.withColumn(‘previous_surname’, lit(‘’))
```